# Request: Mazur' "Arithmetic in the geometry of symmetric spaces"

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does anyone have a copy of Mazur's unpublished notes:

Arithmetic in the geometry of symmetric spaces

that they are willing to post? Thank you!

Comment: Can we repeat the success of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49303/mazurs-unpublished-manuscript-on-primes-and-knots

Comment: I second Chandan's comment. Although not a research question at face value, it is much more valuable than the gazillions of soft questions that show up here regularly.

Comment: Hopefully Barry Mazur will turn up here and give his blessing to online posting of the notes.

Comment: I have emailed the question to him.

Comment: @Chandan, you've gone about it the right way. I voted to close because I did not like the idea of being asked to post something without permission of the author. If I decide to do such a thing on my own authority, that is different. I'm special. 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dear modular1,

I sent the link to your question to [Barry Mazur](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/), and he has very kindly sent the paper to me.  I've got it scanned and sent it back to him, so if you ask him gently, he'll send the pdf file to you.

I'm happy to have helped you in a small way, because there is a very kind soul who helps me in a big way.  His name is [Dino Lorenzini](http://www.math.uga.edu/~lorenz/), and he has sent me some papers which cannot be found anywhere in the closed disk of radius 3000 km centered at Allahabad.  Merci, Dino.

Best,

Chandan

**Addendum**.  With the permission of Barry Mazur, here is the [typescript](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8EHtI8F9qdIXzJ1Qmc1TTZKNEU).  He'll also put it up on his website.

Comment: Dear Chandan,

Thank you! I will write to Barry.

Best,
Modular1