# Request: Kato's article "Lectures on the approach to Iwasawa theory for Hasse-Weil L-functions." Part II

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

The question (similar to [MO.96531](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96531/request-mazur-arithmetic-in-the-geometry-of-symmetric-spaces))  is about the article by Professor Kazuya Kato in this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540571108).
In this article, Professor Kato indicates the contents of the second part.

MathSciNet does not list it, so presumably it is still unpublished.

Several internet searches have not located it.

Does anyone have a copy that they are comfortable with sharing?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. The first part of Aristotle's Poetics, about tragedy, has some mild indications that there was a second part, about comedy, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetics_%28Aristotle%29 . The existence of a copy of the second part is the reason for the murders in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Rose .   

Comment: As with previous questions, I would expect the best thing to do is to ask Professor Kato. You can find contact information for him at the end of this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.3528.pdf 

Comment: Dear SGP, if there were a way of finding out your email address, I would have sent a copy of the article to you.

Comment: @Chandan, I have had pretty good luck by putting, in a comment, a link where an email for me can be found. In my case i put the C.M.L. search site of the AMS. Do you have a department web page with an address for you?

Comment: For my email address, look at any of my papers on the arXiv (http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/au:+dalawat/0/1/0/all/0/1), or try http://www.hri.res.in/~membershri/facmath.html if it works.

Comment: @Chandan, your faculty page works for me. The point about making my own addresses available in these instances is that anonymous users are often willing to write to a single person. I think, even for a hardcore superhero such as quid, he could make a page www.quid.com and an email address quid@gmail and everything would work.  I hope SGP writes to you. 

Comment: Dear @Chandan, So the article does exist? Would you mind sending me a copy?

Comment: @Jagy: Thanks for the wonderful comment about "The name of the rose"; it is one of my favourite books!

Comment: How can I get this paper, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dear SGP,  I hope you (and a few other committed MOers) have received the paper as an email attachment.  However, I will make it publicly available here only if Professor Kato authorises me to do so.

Answer (score 19):

I am Kazuya Kato. All things which I hoped to write in Part 2 are contained in my paper with Takako Fukaya

A formulation of conjectures on p-adic zeta functions in noncommutative Iwasawa theory.

I was hoping to write the Part 2, but the time passed. All things which I wanted to write in Part 2 were generalized to non-commutative Iwasawa theory in the above paper.